# Cufon delay in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cufon

Does anybody have any idea why Cufon has a second delay upon loading the page in Internet Explorer (all versions) - http://www.consolidatemydebt.co.uk

I've got `<script type="text/javascript"> Cufon.now(); </script>` right before the closing `</body>` tag also.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The best way to prevent this flicker (which can also happen in Chrome/FF when the server connection is slow) is by hiding the cúfon text until it has been rendered.

Add document.documentElement.className = 'js'; just below your  tag. This means we can target JavaScript enabled browsers by appending your CSS with .js before each selector.

In your CSS use this selector to temporarily hide content on page load, for example:

h1 { font-size: 2em; }
.js h1 { text-indent: -9999px; }

Then in your JavaScript where you call cúfon include (this is assuming you are also using jQuery):

```
Cufon.replace("h1");
Cufon.now();  
$("h1").css("z-index","0");
```

What this does is hide the content until all your scripts have loaded and cúfon has run then shows the content.

You can also do this using z-index values.

Comment: thanks for the recent upvote but you really should be using @font-face now!

Answer (score 1):

Try to call `<script type="text/javascript">Cufon.now();</script>` right after the `<body>` tag and the `Cufon.replace` right after the element you want to replace. This should fix the flickering problem.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to http://blog.jmedwards.net/post/1484780565/cufon-delay

Add this to your stylesheet

```
.cufon-loading { visibility: hidden;  }
```

to remove the flash/delay in rendering the font.

Once the font is re-rendered, the class is replaced with 'cufon-active'

Answer (score 0):

This is known bug for Cufon. Checkout [Here](http://wiki.github.com/sorccu/cufon/known-bugs-and-issues).

> Known bugs
>
> Internet Explorer: should you not call Cufon.now() just before the
>   closing  tag, there might be a short, visible delay before the text
>   is replaced.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm calling Cufon.now(); right before the closing body tag, and I still get the issue