# Cufón font loading after page loads

Tags: wordpress, cufon

I have a site I'm building, here: http://ericbrockmanwebsites.com/dev2/

I'm using Cufón because the font the client wants doesn't look very good when the user is on a Microsoft system or on Chrome. SEO is not important as it's, for the most part, not really open to the public.

The problem is that the page loads with the default font and then the cufón script kicks in a second or so later - every time a new page is loaded. Just ended up looking very sloppy.

Does anyone how to remedy this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!
cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer works well, since you're using jQuery: [Cufon delay in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116757/cufon-delay-in-internet-explorer?rq=1)

You essentially hide the text until it's rendered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

How about hiding all the content until the content is loaded? ie...

In CSS, hide the body

```
body { display:none; }
```

Then in jQuery when everything is loaded and the window is ready

```
jQuery(window).ready(function() {
  jQuery('body').css({
    'display':'block'
  });
});
```

If the website takes a little while to load you might want to consider using a pre loader instead.

Comment: I've tried this before to no avail, but maybe it's time to revisit it. Let you know how it goes.

Comment: If you do let me know how it goes. If you get any errors in the JavaScript debug console feel free to post them.